# How is PostgreSQL hot standby WAL file restoring triggered?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, wal

Primary server

```
# postgresql.conf
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
archive_timeout = 10
archive_command = 'test ! -f /archive/%f && cp %p /archive/%f'
```

Standby server

```
hot_standby = on
```

I copied `/archive/*` in primary server to `$PGDATA/pg_xlog` in the standby, and nothing happen. When I restart the standby server, I got error messages from server log:

```
2016-11-21 17:56:09 CST [17762-3] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2016-11-21 17:56:09 CST [17762-4] LOG:  record with zero length at 0/6000100
2016-11-21 17:56:09 CST [17762-5] LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
2016-11-21 17:56:09 CST [17762-6] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2016-11-21 17:56:09 CST [17761-1] LOG:  startup process (PID 17762) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2016-11-21 17:56:09 CST [17761-2] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

Questions:

1. Is it enough to sync data to standby server by simply copying `/archive/*` in primary server to `$PGDATA/pg_xlog` in the standby?
2. How and when is the restoring of WAL files triggered in a hot standby server? Does the standby server periodically check its `$PGDATA/pg_xlog` directory for new WAL files? Or do I have to trigger it manually?
3. I am talking about *hot standby*, not *streaming replication*; so I assume I don't have to configure `conninfo`. Am I right?
4. After configuring `hot_standby = on` and restarting the server, I can still do an `INSERT` without error. How to configure to make it really read-only?

Answer (score 3):

That looks a lot like you didn't initialize the standby database correctly.

The log file states that PostgreSQL won't even begin to replicate, because it cannot find a valid checkpoint to start with.

What does the `backup_label` file in your standby's data directory contain? If that file doesn't exist, that's probably the problem.

Did that standby suddenly stop working or has it never worked?
How exactly did you create the standby?

Comment: Steps I followed creating the standby: 1. `psql postgres -c "select pg_start_backup('backup')"`. 2. copy the $PGDATA directory to the standby's filesystem. 3. `psql postgres -c "select pg_stop_backup()"`.  4. Set `hot_standby = on` in  `postgresql.conf`. 5 .Restart postgresql server.

Comment: That looks good (if you have `fsync = on`). Probably you didn't copy enough WAL archives and the one that contains the checkpoint from `backup_label` is not there. You have a `backup_label` file, right? Read the entry `START WAL LOCATION` and make sure that the corresponding WAL file is there.

Answer (score 2):

You must first create the standby from a low level base backup of the master. You *cannot* create a new instance and use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`. I'm guessing that's what you tried to do.

The simplest way to do a suitable base backup is to use `pg_basebackup`. Other options are discussed in the manual, but really, just use:

```
pg_basebackup -X stream -D standby_datadir_location -h master_ip
```

or similar.

Only once you have a valid base backup may you start archive recovery or streaming replication. The simplest way is to enable streaming replication. Let `pg_basebackup` do that for you by passing the `-R` flag.

If you want archive recovery, you should add a `restore_command` to the standby's `recovery.conf` that copies the archives from the archive location to the standby.

It's all covered in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html).